# creating Classes with different identitys using a loop in java

Tags: java, arraylist

Im trying to create classes and putting them into an ArrayList

```
import java.util.*;

public class UserGroup 
{
    ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

    public UserGroup() 
    {

    }

    public void addSampleData() 
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) 
        {
            String iConvert = "User" + Integer.toString(i);
            System.out.println(iConvert);

            userList.add(iConvert(iConvert, iConvert, iConvert));
        }

    }
}
```

was trying to use a string within the loop to change what i call each object

Below is the User class the constructor requires 3 strings that was the reason for the iConverts(iConverts, iConverts, iConverts) 
I was trying to name the object using a String

```
public class User {

    /*
    * contains a username, usertype and names (constructor uses these)
    * methods within getUsername, getUserType, getName and setUserType
    */

    String username;
    String userType;
    String name;

    public User(String username, String userType, String name)
    {

    }

    protected String getUsername()
    {

        return username;
    }

    protected String getUserType()
    {

        return userType;
    }

    protected String getName()
    {

        return name;
    }

    protected void setUserType(String newType)
    {
        userType = newType;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the question and what is iConvert(iConvert, iConvert, iConvert)?

Comment: UserList is an ArrayList  of User's you are adding Strings not User Objects

Comment: You're trying to create *objects*, not *classes*

Comment: Im trying to create objects with different content within it the idea of iConverts was to give them different names and to name the data within different things so each object is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created an ArrayList that will hold User objects, so trying to do

```
UserList.add(iConvert(iConvert, iConvert, iConvert));
```

makes no sense.

You probably want to do this instead (if your User object has 3 strings as constructor parameters):

```
UserList.add(new User(iConvert, iConvert, iConvert));
```

Comment: So i dont want to name the new object as the reference is the index of the arraylist?
but i can name the parameters

Comment: An Object is an instance of a Class, it doesn't really has its own name, it has it's own unique ID already. Remember that it has its own state. This state is determined by its instance variables. When you create a new object calling a parameterized constructor, you usually want to set the values for those variables, for example: `this.username = username`.

Answer (score 2):

If you add an object to your `ArrayList`, then you can get it like:

```
userList.get(0);
userList.get(1);
userList.get(2);
```

So it's not necessary to change the name. By the name, that's not called classes, you are adding objects to the `ArrayList`. Try to do something like this instead.

```
public void addSampleData() 
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) 
    {
        userList.add(User(...));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A object got by default a unique id, dont worry about that.

Just change your code to.

```
userList.add(new User(iConvert));
```

And change the constructor of the User class to:

```
public User(String iConvert) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to remember that String is an immutable type.  Once instantiated, you cannot alter it.  Secondly, constructors can be called only once.  It looks as though you are attempting to call a String constructor a second time.  Next, since you are using Generics to declare what types of ojbects your list will hold, you must make sure that only `User` types are put into it or the compiler will give you an error.

So you need something like

```
ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
   User user = new User("User" + i);
   userList.add(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work

```
        userList.add(iConvert(iConvert, iConvert, iConvert));
```

iConvert is a string instance and you are attempting to call it as though it were a method.